# Using Eclipse's JDT, how do I identify the classpath for a project?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am writing a plug-in that will generate unit tests for a Java class that is selected in Eclipse's Project Explorer.  This plug-in uses a third-party program called Randoop to generate the tests, so I make this happen using `ProcessBuilder`:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
```

where the command that is passed to the ProcessBuilder is a list of Strings, something like

```
["java", "-classpath", "path1;path2;etc", "randoop.main.Main", ...]
```

Within the plug-in I am trying to generate the classpath for Randoop based on the classpath that Eclipse knows about.  Here is some of what I have so far:

```
IClasspathEntry[] resolvedClasspath = javaProject.getResolvedClasspath(true);

for (IClasspathEntry entry : resolvedClasspath) {
    if (entry.getEntryKind() == IClasspathEntry.CPE_SOURCE) {
        IPath outputLocation = entry.getOutputLocation();

        if (outputLocation != null) {
            buf.append(outputLocation.toString());
        }
        else {
            buf.append(entry.getPath().toString());
        }
    }
    else {
        buf.append(entry.getPath().toString());
    }
    buf.append(CLASSPATH_SEP);
}
```

It isn't quite right.  It seems to specify the library jar files okay, but doesn't do so well with identifying the paths to class files corresponding to `CPE_SOURCE` entries.  For example, I see a classpath entry of `/myPkgFragRoot/src/main/java` instead of `myPkgFragRoot/target/classes`.

I seem to have a muddled picture of how Eclipse treats classpaths, so I'm looking for some help.  Firstly, I'm wondering if my high-level approach is wrong.  It seems like I am writing a large amount of code to generate an incorrect classpath.  Is there some simpler way of getting a classpath from an `IJavaProject` than getting the results of `getResolvedClasspath` and iterating through them and manipulating the individual entries? Secondly, if there isn't a simpler way, how should I be locating the class files produced by building the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `outputLocation` is `null`, you have to use the default output location **`javaProject.getOutputLocation()`** instead of `entry.getPath()`.

See [Javadoc of `IClasspathEntry.getOutputLocation()`](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/IClasspathEntry.html#getOutputLocation()):

> Returns:
>
> the full path [...], or **`null` if using default output folder**

If in *Project > Properties: Java Build Path* tab *Source* the check box *Allow output folders for source folders* is not checked, `IClasspathEntry::getOutputLocation()` will always return `null`.